# I want to know if QAction is clicked by left or right mouse button

Tags: c++, qt, qmenu, qaction

I have a `QAction` in `QMenu`. When `QAction` is `triggered()` I would like to know which button did it.

```
connect(YourAction, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(actionclicked()));

void MainWindow::actionclicked(QMouseEvent *e)
{
    if (e->buttons() == Qt::RightButton) 
}
```

I can't do something like this because `triggered()` does not have such argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @mvidelgauz noticed, `QAction` is abstracted from input devices which may triggered the action. Nevertheless, if the action is used in your GUI, it has one or more associated widgets: tool buttons in a toolbar, entries in menu bar and so on. These widgets act like any other widgets, so they receive events which may be filtered with the use of [installEventFilter](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#installEventFilter) and [eventFilter](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#eventFilter). These two methods are inherited from `QObject`, so they are present in almost any Qt class. For example, let's create an application with QMainWindow and QAction called `actionTest`. Then let's turn the main window itself into an action filter for `actionTest`'s associated widgets by overriding main window's `eventFilter` method:

```cpp
bool eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *ev) {
    //Catch only mouse press events.
    if(ev->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonPress) {
        // Cast general event to mouse event.
        QMouseEvent *mev = static_cast<QMouseEvent*>(ev);
        // Show which button was clicked.
        if(mev->button() == Qt::LeftButton) {
            qDebug() << "Left button!";
        }
        if(mev->button() == Qt::RightButton) {
            qDebug() << "Right button!";
        }
    }
    // In this example we just showed the clicked button. Pass the event
    // for further processing to make QAction slots work.
    return QMainWindow::eventFilter(obj, ev);
}
```

Then we need to install event filter object for all watched objects, which are widgets in our case. Let's do it in main window constructor:

```cpp
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    for(auto wgtPtr : ui->actionTest->associatedWidgets()) {
        wgtPtr->installEventFilter(this);
    }
}
```

Finally, add a slot for `triggered()` signal handling:

```cpp
void on_actionTest_triggered() {
    qDebug() << "Action triggered!";
}
```

Now if you click the action menu entry with left mouse button, it will print

```
Left button!
Action triggered!
```

while for right mouse button the result will be

```
Right button!
Action triggered!
```

Note that widget event filtering is always performed before `triggered()` signal emission.

The above code is just an example, and `MainWindow` class is not the best place to host `eventFilter` method. In real code you may either:

1. Create dedicated `QObject` subclass(es) for `QAction` widgets event filtering.
2. Subclass `QAction` and override it's `eventFilter` method. In this case you may just save the result of `QMouseEvent::button()` in the `QAction` subclass object and later use it in `triggered()` signal handler. There is a minor inconvenience that Qt creator (at least up to v3.2.1) does not allow you to "promote" `QAction`s in it's form designer, so you'll need to add actions to menus manually in window constructor.
3. Subclass `QMenu`, `QToolBar`, etc..,  and make them action filters? I don't know how can it be better than two former variants.

See also [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/eventsandfilters.html) about Qt event system.

Let's clarify case 2. Assume the class inherited from `QAction` is called `MyAction`. In order to make it work you need to install `MyAction` objects as filters for themselves (their widgets, to be more specific). You need to do it after widgets were created, so installing filter in `MyAction` constructor may be premature and lead to crashes. Better place for filter installation is a constructor of a class which owns `MyAction` object. Typically it's a widget or window class. So just add

```
for(auto wgtPtr : ui->myActionObject->associatedWidgets()) {
    wgtPtr->installEventFilter(ui->myActionObject);
}
```

to your window constructor after `ui->setupUi(this)` call. This code is like in the above example, but we use `ui->myActionObject` instead of `this` object as filter.

Comment: Can I make eventFilter in class I use as QAction? I already have class which inherits from QAction, and I use it in my application. I overrided eventFilter method, but nothing is happening. Do I have to install it somewhere?

Comment: @S.llous surely you can. I added clarification for case 2 from my answer which should make your code work. Try to print something to `qDebug()` from your `eventFilter` method to make sure it works properly.

Comment: Will this work when I want to use it on `QSystemTrayIcon`? My application does not have GUI, only `QActions` in `QSystemTrayIcon`.

Comment: @S.llous do those actions reside in a menu, which appears when you click tray icon? This should work.

Answer (score 3):

`triggered()` cannot have this argument by design because it by itself is not necessarily result of a mouse event:

> This signal is emitted when an action is activated by the user; for example, when the user clicks a menu option, toolbar button, **or presses an action's shortcut key combination, or when trigger() was called**

You need to connect to mouse events if you need `QMouseEvent` as parameter. In fact Qt itself emits `triggered()` when (but not only as I highlighted in doc quote) framework receives mouse event from menu. So it looks like you'll need to do a similar thing in your code and add your own logic.

P.S. [This discussion](http://www.qtcentre.org/archive/index.php/t-59171.html) might be interesting for you